# How to extract data from Json array?

Tags: java, json

[image: Json object]

Using `Jsonobject` I extracted data from `RawmatrixData` and stored it in Object:

```
org.json.JSONObject item = Fir.getJSONObject(i); Object value1 = item.get("RawMatrixData")`
```

Now i want to replace data `342771123181` with some string value, how to achieve this?

I tried with `ArrayList<String>` and `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`.

"LstMatrixFirmInfo": [
      {
        "RawMatrixData": "[[342771123181,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null],[3427714486446,1,2,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,28.99,28.99,28.99,25,4.81,4.81,4.81,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]]]}

Comment: copy and paste json instead of posting as an image

Comment: @Dan  updated Question

Answer (score -1):

Is RawMatrixData supposed be a string like in the image or JSON Array.

If RawMatrixData is supposed to be string then maybe converted to JSONArray

I would just use string replace.

`String replacedText = Fir.getString('RawMatrixData').replace('342771123181', 'foobar')
Fir.push('RawMatrixData', replacedText);`

The above can be done in one line but for ease of understanding it hasn't. First line gets your string from the Json object then replace the number with foobar.
Then text is pushed back on to the json object overwriting the old value.
The above code i believe sorts out your problem based on the picture you provided.

If the RawMatrixData was supposed to be a JSON array and not a string then in that case you would have to traverse the whole array replace as you go.

Comment: Hi Just let him know how can he convert 2d JSON array to `arrayList` hope it will work for him :)